# Change the background color of a plot

Tags: javascript, plotly.js

I am using Plotly.js for plots on [my website](http://www.whereisroadster.com). I can't for the life of me figure out how to change the background color to anything besides white. Can that be done, or am I just missing something? Space isn't white, it is black, it would be nice to see it as such...

[image]

Comment: It's unfortunate that such a good plotting library has such terrible documentation.  +1

Comment: Yeah, but it is getting somewhat better over time...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
layout= {
      plot_bgcolor:"black",
      paper_bgcolor:"#FFF3"
}
```